# Why does my for loop only run when inside of a while loop?

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, selenium

Hi for some reason this code works. I cannot figure out why:

```
some = 0
n = 5
while some == 0:
    for title in itertools.islice(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='link-title']"), n):
        print(title.text)
        some += 1
```

if I remove the while loop and only run the for loop, I have no output.

My goal here is to collect the first five titles present in a webpage, hence the itertools. Originally, I tried doing this with the while loop, but it just provided me all the titles. This is how I came across this strange solution that seemingly works.

When I try to run it with the for loop alone, without the while loop, it gives me no output. I don't get the list of title that I want.

But I don't like it. I can't figure out why it works

Comment: I'm confused. Which is the code that produces no output? You said it was the one where you removed the `while` loop.

Comment: The while loop has no effect here. Surely, you are doing something else.

Comment: @Mohammad: (or the `while` loop will be an infinite loop if the `find_elements_by_css_selector()` returns empty)

Comment: @quamrana edited my question to only include one code snippet so it's less confusing. i did find the reason thanks to the accepted answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is about time. Your code has to wait till elements are fully loaded.
You can use selenium pre-built timer command

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "link-title")))
```

or another easier solution

```py
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually ended up using driver.implicit_wait(2), but if it weren't for this comment I wouldn't have figured out the issue. You just saved me a lot of time!